# metadata.downloadurl in my xcode app giving download link instead of viewing link

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

[image: Upload Image Code]I want to upload a file to **firebase storage** using swift xcode.
I am able to do it successfully and i am also able to add the metadata.downloadURl() correctly in my firebase database but the problem is that the url i am getting is **download url** instead of **viewing url**.
when i am uploading file to firebase storage manually and than accessing the download url, it is an url which when accessed shows the image in web browser and on the other hand when i am uploading the image using app,the url i am getting is an url which automatically downloads the image.
now i want an image url which dont download but only views the image in browser.

please help me for the same.

Comment: Please add more details what is your metadata put,
However, this is an example of a link that view the image not download
check your url same this  
`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-92920.appspot.com/o/e578e66626ac62b4d9f60f94b2ee3d14.png?alt=media&token=2bfb0e89-4fc6-4cc6-aba8-48244ebe7dce`

Comment: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ddit-dbba1.appspot.com/o/Images%2FldcUEYgpUNe5m8CLp9VA?alt=media&token=daba6755-a6e5-4aa2-aea8-5421535bfd0a .  This is downloadable link and it was uploaded by app

Comment: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ddit-dbba1.appspot.com/o/2018-01-16-PHOTO-00003402%202.jpg?alt=media&token=6cdcc09a-c752-4f74-a2ba-f020195a6dbd . this is viewable link uploaded manually

Comment: In this case you have a problem metadata ,
Make sure of them after upload them what is metadata values

Comment: please add your code upload image to firebase

Comment: var data = Data()
            data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.8)!
            var progress : Int
            var stringValue : String
            let storage = Storage.storage()
            let storageRef = storage.reference()
            let imageRef = storageRef.child("Images/"+randomString(20));
            let uploadTask = imageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                let downloadurl = metadata?.downloadURL()
                print(downloadurl)
                self.Fdownloadurl = (downloadurl?.absoluteString)!

Comment: add this code `let metaData = StorageMetadata()
metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
 imageRef.putData(data, metadata: metaData)`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var data = Data() 
data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.8)!
var progress : Int 
var stringValue : String 
let storage = Storage.storage() 
let storageRef = storage.reference() 
let imageRef = storageRef.child("Images/"+randomString(20));
let metaData = StorageMetadata() 
metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
 let uploadTask = (imageData, metadata: metaData, completion: { (metadata, error) in
let downloadurl = metadata?.downloadURL()
 print(downloadurl) 
})
```

add this line in your code

> let metaData = StorageMetadata() 
>       metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

please look this documentation  [firebase metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/file-metadata)